# Regex to get a string following a string

Tags: regex

If i have a line that ends like

version is: 1.10.0.1001

i'm looking for a regex to get the version number but can't figure out how to get the string following "version is:"

Comment: ignore all the inputs upto `:` and consider the rest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind i figured it out

(?<=version is: ).*

This won't include "version is: " in the match and will take any number of characters after it

Answer (score 2):

Use parantheses to capture values.
If you only want the entire version value in one string, this would be enough

```
if(/version is:(.*)/.test(yourString)) {
    versionNum = RegExp.$1;
}
```

Here versionNum will store `1.10.0.1001`.

But if you wanted the individual numbers between the dots, you would have to go with something like this:

```
if(/version is:(\d+\.)(\d+\.)(\d+.)(\d+)/.test(yourString)) {
    majorBuild = RegExp.$1;
    minorBuild = RegExp.$2;
    patch = RegExp.$3;
    revision = RegExp.$4;
}
```

Basically the variables will hold values like this

```
majorBuild = 1
minorBuild = 10
patch = 0
revision = 1001
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

use a capture (parentheses).  Try

```
s/version is:(.*)/\1/g
```

also, what regex engine are you using?  You may need to escape the colon, and determine if magic is on/off

or better yet, just remove version is: and everything before it

```
s/.*version is://g
```

Comment: what guarantees do you have about your input?

Answer (score 0):

Regex using java:

```
System.out.println("abcd version is:1.23.33.444".replaceAll("^(?:.*:)(.*)$","$1"));
System.out.println("abcd version is:1.23.33.444".replaceAll("^(?:.*:)",""));
```